# How to select an option from the auto suggestions using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autosuggest, selenium4

I'm trying to select an option from the auto-suggestions after sending a text within the search field of the [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) website. But I'm unable to find any of those suggestions.

Code trials:

```
driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-by"))).send_keys("selenium")
```

Snapshot of the auto-suggestions:

[image: documentations]

Can anyone help me out please to select any of the auto-suggestions?

Comment: You can send the complete text option and then send an enter
or you can run javascript with selenium.
For these cases, I prefer to inject javascript

Comment: I got the source of the auto-suggestions in Chrome by typing something into the search box and hitting `Ctrl-Shift-I` to open up Inspect in the Dev Tools. You can then expand that div to find the divs for each auto-suggestion.

Comment: Would you be able to map it to python if I give it to you in java ?

Comment: @WilfredClement Sure, I will take that even. Feel free to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `autocomplete-suggestions` is the `div` that holds all the `autocomplete-suggestion`'s.

Here is a snip of the elements
[image]

To capture the elements I  used the `f8` button when searching for selenium, that way the elements don't disappear.

Here is a code snip for visualization:

```
def highlight_element(element):
    driver_elem = element.parent

    def apply_style(s):
        driver_elem.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                                   element, s)

    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
    sleep(0.5)
    apply_style(original_style)

driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-by")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#search-by").send_keys("selenium")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".autocomplete-suggestions  .autocomplete-suggestion")))
for ele in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".autocomplete-suggestions  .autocomplete-suggestion"):
    highlight_element(ele)
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 for @Moshe Slavin's answer. The `autocomplete-suggestions` is the div that holds all the `autocomplete-suggestion's`

In order to capture the elements, I used the `getPageSource()` to print out the elements in the page.

And once I figured out the element the rest of the code below is self explanatory

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("autocomplete-suggestion")));

List<WebElement> abc = driver.findElements(By.className("autocomplete-suggestion"));

String value = "Remote WebDriver client";

List<String> def = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++) {

            //Get the values and store it in a list
            def.add(abc.get(i).getAttribute("data-title"));

        }

        if (def.contains(value))

            abc.get(def.indexOf(value)).click();

        else
            System.out.println("Value not present");
```